# How to trigger zepto swipe events with device interactions

Tags: javascript, mobile, trigger.io, zepto

I have this straight forward zepto swipe code

```
$(function(){

  $(document).on('swipeRight',function(e){
    alert("right");
  });

  $(document).on('swipeLeft', function(e){
    alert("left");
  });

});
```

I can't seem to trigger this from the iOSSimulator or on an actual device.
I can however call `$(document).trigger('swipeRight')` from a console and trigger the events. I'm not seeing any obvious error output

using Zepto v1.0-1-ga3cab6c

IOs 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to include the zepto 'touch' module.